# Connect client to TCP Server

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

How to connect with this plugin to TCP Server (written in another language autoit, without http layer)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-socket.io

I connected like this

```
var socketIO = new SocketIO('http://192.168.1.10:5556', {});
```

using this below and everything works but I need connect without http protocol

https://github.com/Gonzalo2310/PanelDraw-Server/blob/master/index.js
only providing ip and port

cause my server is written in another language 
and looks like this

https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/98820-tcp-server-client-examples-to-learn-from/